# How to prevent scrolling to the right in this jsfiddle

Tags: html, css

I have the following jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KfPOQ/

using a web browser it is fine however when on the ebay app on iphone or ipad i have to scroll right to see the full page how do I eliminate this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the content of the page fit within your viewport (or screen) dimensions for the given media type. You can have different stylesheets based on the [media type in a link/stylesheet tag](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/style/media). Say, for the iphone, use `media="handheld"` and try to keep the content within around `600px`, or whatever looks good on your mobile device.

Here is another [resource](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) from w3c.

Comment: One question if i have done the styles on the same webpage and they start with # when i move them into the stylesheet what does it change to?

Comment: Np, I added another resource that might be more helpful. If I understand your question, the css syntax won't change, but you might have multiple stylesheets with the same selectors, but different css values for the different medias.